# Is is possible to specifically search for crashing stocks?

Tags: stock-markets, shares

A part of my personal investment strategy is to buy shares that have just fallen to a very low point. Recent examples include Zalando and TomTom, both of which I trust to recover soon.

Looking for such crashes has been quite cumbersome though, reading lots of articles, manually skimming through graphs and only occasionally finding what I'm looking for.

Is there a way this could be automated to an extent? I'm thinking along the lines of getting a list of stocks that have just fallen >10% within a day or so, so that I only need to read about the reason and determine whether a quick recovery is plausible.

Comment: search for 'stock screener'

Comment: It is better to search for outbreaking/exploding stocks and profit from their gains. A stock can always go lower than you think, if you think it goes only to 0.01 there is also 0.001. Never catch a falling knife.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can screen for one day drops in US stocks with:

The FINVIZ stock screener offers percent change for 7,000+ stocks.  It's for current prices and AFAIK, the free screener does not offer historical calculations (change over past 3 days, 10 days, etc.)

https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&o=change

The WSJ Market Data page lists largest one day  daily percent and point winners and losers for NYSE and NASDAQ stocks.  It offers a calendar so you can see one day largest winners and losers on a previous date (years worth of data).

http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-losenyse-loser-20180920.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar

There are ways to calculate "X" day look backs (ROC over some number of previous days) but they involve data subscriptions and software so I'll leave it at that.